Thoughts on multiple short repeating videos on screen

Are multiple videos playing at once bad practice? Starting to see this more on higher end brand sites.
See Gucci.com services area on homepage for example. 3 Video tiles with description text.
Each are set to auto play. And each have a pause button which is important.

Moving content in general is problematic, and for WCAG compliance, such content must be pausable. See WCAG SC 2.2.2 for more. It points out these as potential problems:

Content that moves or auto-updates can be a barrier to anyone who has trouble reading stationary text quickly as well as anyone who has trouble tracking moving objects. It can also cause problems for screen readers.
Moving content can also be a severe distraction for some people. Certain groups, particularly those with attention deficit disorders, find blinking content distracting, making it difficult for them to concentrate on other parts of the Web page.

Are 3 autoplaying animations worse than 1 autoplaying animation? I'd the answer is a clear "it depends": I've seen sites with a single video playing in the background which were more distracting than this, but I've also seen sites which felt better to use. The videos they use don't really play nicely together as their motion vectors are all over the place. The animations when scrolling down the page also screams more of a "quick job by a webdesign agency which made things look flashy" than "well thought out UX solution".

Thanks Leo, seems like there isn't a definitive answer. However, could easily bring more issues than it's worth.
